# Calculating Volterra like operator norm from $L^2([0,1])$ to $L^1([0,1]).$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Define $K:L^2[0,1]\to L^1[0,1]$ by 
$$
Kf(x) = x^{-4/3} \int_0^x f(t) \ dt.
$$
Find the operator norm of $K$.

I was able to show that $K$ is a bounded linear operator by
\begin{align*}
\|Kf\|_1 &= \int_0^1 \bigg|x^{-4/3} \int_0^x f(t) \ dt\bigg|\ dx \leq \int_0^1 x^{-4/3} \int_0^x |f(t)| \ dt \ dx\leq \int_0^1 \bigg( x^{-4/3} \|f\|_2 \int_0^x 1 \ dt\bigg) \ dx\\
&=\|f\|_2 \int_0^1 x^{-5/6} \ dx = 6 \|f\|_2.
\end{align*}
This implies that $\|K\|_{op} \leq 6$.  But improving this upper-bound and finding an appropriate lower-bound has been troublesome.  For example maximizing over monomials of the form $f(t) = at^r$ with $a$ chosen so that $\|f\|_2=1$, I obtain that $2.802 \leq \|K\|_{op}.$  How should I proceed?

Comment: Try to make all of your inequalities equalities. You should try to put most of the weight of $f$ close to $0$ to make Cauchy Schwarz hold, and have $f$ be non-negative so that the absolute value bounds are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited - thanks to Professor Vector for finding a mistake of mine.

By Tonelli, $\int_0^1 x^{-4/3}\int_0^x |f(t)|dtdx = \int_0^1 |f(t)| \int_t^1 x^{-4/3}dxdt = 3\int_0^1 |f(t)|(t^{-1/3}-1)dt$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz, $3\int_0^1 |f(t)|(t^{-1/3}-1) \le 3||f||_2||t^{-1/3}-1||_2 = 3||f||_2$. Equality can be obtained by making Cauchy-Schwarz hold, which occurs if $f(t) \equiv t^{-1/3}-1$ (which is always non-negative).

Comment: The correct equation is $\int_0^1 |f(t)| \int_t^1 x^{-4/3}dxdt = 3\int_0^1 |f(t)|(t^{-1/3}-1)dt\le3\|f\|_2,$ with equality for $f(t)=t^{-1/3}-1.$ So both of you made a mistake. ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know how to distribute. LOL thanks

Comment: But I don't think he made a mistake. 3 is greater than 2.802. It just turns out my Tonelli trick gives 3 instead of 6, which is better

Comment: You're right, his bound is not incorrect, just weak. His mistake was to limit the maximization to functions $f(t)=at^r.$ So what, will you edit the correction into your answer, or shall I do that?

Comment: Eh, you can get the points if you want. if not, I'll update my answer

Comment: Do that, please, the crucial idea was Tonelli (or Fubini), and it's yours.